# Error when trying to draw graphics in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, error-handling

When i trying to execute this code i take 'Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.' error.

```
v(1)=0;
g=9.81;
m=68.1;
c=12.5;
t=0:0.5:8;
for i=1:0.5:8
   v(i+1)=v(i)+([g-((c/m)*v(i))].*(i+1-i));
end
plot(t,v);
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Velocity (m/s)');
```

Answer (score 0):

What would we expect MATLAB to do when it encounters `v(1.5)`, where `v` is a vector (an array)? As you have just found out, MATLAB requires array indices to always be integers, starting from 1 (or logical arrays, but that's not the case here), otherwise it throws an error. You can think of these indices as discrete positions in computer memory, or tiny drawers in a huge dresser (the dresser is so huge that it has millions, no, billions of drawers). It doesn't make any sense to try to store an object somewhere *between* two drawers. If someone ordered you to do so in real life, how would you react? Well, now you're thinking like MATLAB. You should therefore be able to realize your code needs to be modified so that it reads:

```
v(1)=0;
%[...]
t=0:0.5:8;
for i=2:17
  v(i)=v(i-1)+([g-((c/m)*v(i-1))].*( 0.5*(i-1)+1-0.5*(i-1) ));
  %was the `.*(i+1-i)' (i.e. the multiplicative identity) in the original code a typo?
end
```

Notice that, unlike the original program, the above code also computes the `v` associated with `t==0.5`.